# Test google credentials using google drive api

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I want to have a button which will check if my credentials are valid or not.Credentials may be using service account or user account. Now, wandering if google drive api has any such for testing the credentials. Thinking in case of the user account credentials (oauth2), it looks like would be a bit problem as one has to enter the username/password of the user if some other person wants to check his clientID, secret etc. And in case of service account, looks like it should have some api as such. Please suggest. I am using python.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rely first on OAuth for the authentication of a user. Drive API has the "About" resource, which you could request to get the current user credentials and validate on your side. Here is a link of the implementation for Ruby: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get

Comment: In case of service account - I think this should be working, but i was wandering when in case of the user account, he needs to get the email account credentials to use this api ... right !. So when if someone(admin) is applying keys to its users then service account should only work with this api, and since the admin should not be having the users credentials this should not work. I am not sure what I am thinking is right or wrong... just a thinking!